# django: restrict url reachable only from one view

Tags: python, django, django-views

i'm new in Django.
I have a form once filled i keep the datas and redirect to another page, but i notice if i put the correct url i can access to this second page without passing by the first form.

here is my urls:

```
 urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'newworkflow/$','access_mgmt.views.newworkflowform'),
    url(r'newrole/$','access_mgmt.views.newrole'),             
)
```

So if in my browser url i put /newrole i get the page but i want to have access to it only if the form on the first page "/newworkflow/ is filled.

Is it possible to restrict the access to the second page only if the first form page is filled?

Comment: Are you submitting the form data to the second page?

Comment: i don't realy know how to pass datas to the second page with redirect() method, but it's a good idea, pass datas from first page and if needed an additional argument boolean say if the first form is filled or not...

Comment: just to add a note here: have you tried form wizards? Django comes with an optional “form wizard” application that splits forms across multiple Web pages. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only by recording somewhere - say in the session - that the user has completed page1, and checking that in the view for page2.